# Write big messages to socket buffer vs lots of small messages

Tags: sockets, tcp

My question is quite simple. Assume we have a `TCP` socket server which is going to send *10 length prefixed messages each second* to its connected clients. each message has size of *500 bytes*. Is it better to merge all those *10 messages* and call `socket.write()` once with a *5000 bytes* lengthed message each second , or it is better to call `socket.write()` *10 times per second* ? Which one cause lower latency ?

Comment: TCP will coalesce it anyway. There is always a benefit in buffering, as you save on system calls, but the effect at the receiver will be much the same.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for reply, can you exactly mention some of buffering benefits? How much reducing system calls can help?

Comment: At only 10 messages per second, you’re unlikely to be able to measure any speed up via manual buffering.  (If it were 10,000 messages per second, it would be a different story)

Comment: Btw your real fun will begin when you have 12 clients receiving your data as fast as you can send it, and one client (connected over a 57.6k modem via a soda straw) receiving data at only 1kByte/sec.  Then you get to try to handle that gracefully, without impacting the ‘fast’ clients or DOS’ing the server :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner what if there are 20K connected clients , does buffering make sense ?

Comment: I'm not sure TCP makes sense with 20K connected clients.  In any case, if you wait up to 1 second before calling `write()`, you will have added up to 1 second of latency to your data, in order to save several microseconds worth of CPU cycles on the server.  That's probably not a good tradeoff.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner (For us) the only important factor is handling more clients on each server. That 1 second latency doesn't matter at all for us.

Comment: The benefit of buffering is reduced system calls. I already stated that. The benefit of reduced system calls is less CPU usage and less time spent inside single-user code in the kernel, which increases concurrency of the whole system.